# Spring Boot: Application Context fails to load external component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I did a sample spring boot application to send metrics to Hosted Graphite. For that i added a class Metrics Manager .

```
@Component
public class MetricsManager {


    @Autowired
    private MetricRegistry metricsRegistry;

    private GraphiteReporter reporter;

    /**
     * Method connects Boot project with graphite server to push the metrics
     * data. It registers with graphite server only if the graphite
     * information(hostname, port) is available.
     *
     * Property ‘graphiteConfigParams’ should be configured in following format.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void registerGraphiteReporter() {
        try {

                final Graphite graphite = new Graphite(new InetSocketAddress("<url>", <port>));
                reporter = GraphiteReporter.forRegistry(metricsRegistry)
                                           .prefixedWith("service.testing")
                                           .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                           .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                           .filter(new FilterMetrics()).build(graphite);
                reporter.start(30 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void destropMetricsContext() {

        if (reporter != null)
            reporter.stop();
    }


}
```

So when the application runs the metrics is exported fine.

The below is the controller class

Controller Class

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Bu when i run tests for this Hello controller, am facing exceptions when the application context loads,

Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(HelloController.class)
@ComponentScan({"com.metric.test"})
public class HelloControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testMalformedRequest() throws Exception{
        System.err.println("");
    }

}
```

I am getting the below exception

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field metricsRegistry in com.metric.test.manager.MetricsManager required a bean of type 'com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry' in your configuration.

So when i create a configuration class and define it as bean,the test passes fine.

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public MetricRegistry getMetricsRegistry(){
        return new MetricRegistry();
    }

}
```

My question is

Please let me know why the exception is thrown only when running junits? Even though the auto wiring was working fine when the application is running, without defining it in a configuration.